# Passing List of objects via querystring to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a situation where I need to pass a List of objects to an MVC Controller, but I'm not sure how to format this in the querystring.  The reason I would want to do this is because this is not a web application, it's a web service that accepts data via the querystring and routes it to a controller that does the work.

So, given a class called MyParam with properties A & B, how can I construct a querystring that will pass data to the following controller method:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(List<MyParam> ParamList)
```

I've tried using the MVC framework to RedirectToAction and RedirectToResult to see what it comes up with, but I assume that my n00bness with MVC is causing me to make a mistake because it never passes the data correctly and MyMethod always has null for the parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may find the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) useful for the wire format of lists you need to use if you want the default model binder to successfully parse the request into a strongly typed array of objects. Example of query string:

```
[0].Title=foo&[0].Author=bar&[1].Title=baz&[1].Author=pub...
```

where:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

will successfully bind to:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(IEnumerable<Book> books) { ... }
```

Comment: It binds, but doesn't actually pass the data.  I just get the default values for each object.

Comment: @dudemonkey, this should work, I am using it almost on a daily basis. Checkout the blog post which provides specific examples and double check that you don't have typos.

Comment: you're right.  In my code I didn't have accessor (get/set) methods for the properties.  Once I added them in, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Note, if the book class had an array prop `public string[] References{ get; set;}` then the format would be `[0].References[0]=foo&[0].References[1]=bar...`

Comment: This was very helpful for even when you're not passing an array via get, but a single object. IE `?Title=foo&Author=bar` for a passing a single book object via GET.  Thanks.

Comment: Under WebApi (maybe mvc as well) you need to add the [ModelBinder] attribute ahead of the IEnumerable<Book> type in the parameter list for MyMethod().

Comment: How pass data with Axios to action

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the information provided I don't think you want what you think you want. In your case on the client you POST the data to the controller. Not use a querystring.

ok since you have to use querystring. my new answer:
serialize object, convert it to base64 string and pass it, then convert it back.

Comment: Unfortunately, as per the requirements, it has to be GET.  Everything has to get passed via the querystring as this will be consumed by unsophisticated clients.

Comment: I'll ask around but we will drink to you and your problems at lunch. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the JsonValueProvider works much better than the normal ValueProvider for binding to a list. Simply convert your data to a JSON object like so:

```
<YourRoute>?ParamList=[{SomeProperty:'Value'},{SomeProperty:'Value'}];
```

And the JsonValueProvider will take care of the rest. This is assuming you have the ability to say "post this data as Json".

I also disclaim whether or not this would be a good idea.