# How to pass a dictionary from Java Script Angular client to MVC3 server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs, http

Trying to pass a dictionary from JS to MVC with no success. The data (reportIdAndStatus in mvc controller) is null.

I'm using angular $resource and MVC 3. Thanks.

Angular Controller:

```
var reportStatusdictionary = {};
//build a dictionary
            for (var x = 0; x < reports.length; x++) {
                reportStatusdictionary[reports[x].Id] = reports[x].StatusId
            }

reportsService.getReportStatusComment({ reportStatusdictionary: reportStatusdictionary }
```

Angular Resource Definition:

```
 getReportStatusComment:
        {
            method: 'GET',
            params: { reportIdAndStatus: '@reportIdAndStatus', command: 'GetReportStatusComment' },
            isArray: false
        }
```

MCV Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetReportStatusComment(Dictionary<Guid, int> reportIdAndStatus)
```

Request In Browser:

[image]

Comment: Try to send dictionary from server to client and capture the format and try to send the same.

Comment: Why you not using POST metod ? Should be easier

Comment: @user3314659 since I'm not changing any resources

Comment: OK so how can your url looks like ?

Comment: See the image I attached in the question (under "Request In Browser")

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dictionary,I'd recommend creating a view model for simplicity and ease of debugging purposes. You can do as below:

1. Create view model like below:

   ```
      public class ReportViewModel
      {
          public Guid Id{get;set;}
          public int StatusId{get;set;} 
      }
   ```
2. Then your controller will look like

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public string GetReportStatusComment(IEnumerable<ReportViewModel> reportViewModel)
   ```
3. Then your get url will be

   `http://localhost:53854/report/getreportstatuscomment?[0].id=guidValue1&[0].StatusId=1&[1].id=guidValue2&[1].StatusId=2`

   You can easilty construct the url structure like this in your JavaScript Code. You can read more on model binding at [@Darin Dimitrov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806216/passing-list-of-objects-via-querystring-to-mvc-controller), [Phil Haack's blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) and [MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).

**Update**

If you don't want to build that url structure then you can send JSON to server.

Comment: Thanks but personally I tend to always use primitives \ built-in types when possible thus a view model option is an overhead for me. Regarding the MSDN article, it explains the how to build a costume value provider, which is again an overhead for the problem I presented. I predict the solution to be very simple, since I'm trying to do a very simple operation.